# Python inserting element to a list varying with each iteration

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, loops

I am trying to insert an element in the list at multiple instances. But by doing this, the length of the list is constantly changing. So, it is not reaching the last element.

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a']
aq = len(my_list)
for i in range(aq):
  if my_list[i] == 'a':
    my_list.insert(i+1, 'g')
    aq = aq+1

print(my_list)
```

The output I am getting is -

```
['a', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a']
```

The output I am trying to get is -

```
['a', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'g']
```

How can I get that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing `aq` in the loop does not change the `range`.  That created an iterator when you entered the loop, and that iterator won't change.  There are two ways to do this.  The easy way is to build a new list:

```
newlist = []
for c in my_list:
    newlist.append(c)
    if c == 'a':
        newlist.append('g')
```

The trickier way is to use `.find()` to find the next instance of 'a' and insert a 'g' after it, then keep searching for the next one.

Comment: Wonder how can use `find()` to search this list of string?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice way to write it using the built-in [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a']
my_list = list(chain.from_iterable((x, "g") if x == "a" else x for x in my_list))
# ['a', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'g']
```

Here, every occurance of `"a"` is replaced with `"a", "g"` in the list, otherwise the elements are left alone.